# Fixing layers that cannot be synched in ArcGIS Field Maps

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, arcgis-field-maps

Some of my layers in Field Maps have the error message:

> Synch is not enabled.

When, in AGOL, I "show item details" for the layer, and click "Settings" there is no checkbox for "Enable Sync (required for offline use and collaboration)."  For other layers I can find this checkbox.

What is wrong with the layers that lack it and how can I fix it?

Comment: What can you tell us about one layer that you cannot sync?  It’s data source is what I’d look at first.

Comment: Do you see the enable editing option in the settings? Did you try making it public first?

Answer (score 0):

I exported the shapefile data, repaired the geometry in ArcMap, uploaded it to AGOL and that seems to have fixed it.